# why does an object's property change when I have already inserted them to a list?

Tags: c#, object, if-statement

I initialized and object and then in each if statementI add the object to a list. The list of object will have the properties of the last if statement and I don't know why. Am I supposed to make a new object each if statement?

```
            var msgObj = new MessageName();
            msgObj.ServerID = serverList[i].EBCPServerID;

            if(keyValuePairs.ContainsKey("rar"))
            {
                msgObj.MessageID = MsgList["rar"]; msgObj.DiagnosticCnt = 0; msgObj.DiagnosticStr = keyValuePairs["rar"]; 
                msgNameList.Add(msgObj);
            }

            if(keyValuePairs.ContainsKey("uptime_in_seconds"))
            {
               msgObj.MessageID= MsgList["uptime_in_seconds"]; msgObj.DiagnosticCnt= Convert.ToInt32(keyValuePairs["uptime_in_seconds"]); msgObj.DiagnosticStr = "";
               msgNameList.Add(msgObj);
            }
           //etc.
            InsertIntoSQL(msg
```

NameList);

When I look at msgNameList at the end, it's all objects with the properties I set as the last one. However when I look at "msgNameList.Add(msgObj);", the msgObj is correct for each.

Comment: yes, new `MessageName` object each time you add it to list

Comment: Please show us the entire method for the code sample you have in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the `MessageID` property on the single `msgObj` object that you have initialized, and then you're adding that single `msgObj` to the `msgNameList`, twice (as long as both if statement predicates are true). You would need to create a new `msgObj` if you want the different `MessageID` properties to be distinct when they're added to the list.

Think of it this way -- if you only have one sheet of paper in front of you (i.e. the `msgObj`) and you write at the top of the piece of paper "Hello", if you were to ever write at the top of the same piece of paper again, you'd need to erase "Hello" before you wrote something else. In your case, you'd rather write "Hello" and then take your original piece of paper to a photocopier and copy it before filing it away somewhere (i.e. putting it in the list).

Comment: @bradkey I don't get why if you add the object to the list with that property, it can change later. I just thought once you put it into the the list it's final so I can keep changing that object's properties and then add them to the lsit so it has the specific properties... guess not.

Comment: @jjss this has everything to do with how the language handles objects and their properties (call-by reference vs. value / pass-by reference vs. value). In this case, a copy of the object is not being placed in the list -- the actual object is being placed in the list. That is, the same object that you are then updating again in the second if statement. You would need to create a new `msgObj` to place in the list rather than just updating the original one.

Comment: @jjss going back to my (lame) paper example, when you add the `msgObj` to the list, you're not photocopying the paper that says "Hello" and filing it away somewhere. You are taking the actual single piece of paper that you have and carrying it around with you.